# Select items from a combobox and write index of selected value to an INI file during installation

Tags: combobox, inno-setup

How to make the user select an item from a combobox and then write it to an INI file as a number (01, 02, 03, ..., 18)? I generated this code but I do not know what else to do. If you could help me I would be very grateful

```pascal
[INI]
Filename: "{app}\rev.ini"; Section: "steamclient"; Key: "RankLevel"; String: ""

[Code]
var
  NewComboBox1: TNewComboBox;

procedure RedesignWizardForm;
begin
  { NewComboBox1 }
  NewComboBox1 := TNewComboBox.Create(WizardForm);
  with NewComboBox1 do
  begin
    Name := 'NewComboBox1';
    Parent := WizardForm.SelectDirPage;
    Left := ScaleX(0);
    Top := ScaleY(120);
    Width := ScaleX(145);
    Height := ScaleY(21);
    Text := 'Alcon';
    Items.Text := 'Alcon' + #13#10 +
         'Aguila' + #13#10 +
         'Elite' + #13#10 +
         'Pro';
    ItemIndex := 0;
  end;

  NewComboBox1.TabOrder := 5;
end;

procedure InitializeWizard();
begin
  RedesignWizardForm;
end;
```

Comment: When do you want to write the file (in what part of the installation process)? What is a "natural number"?

Comment: In a custom page after the components section, but that code I am putting as an example, and a normal number 01, 02, 03 ...., 18

Comment: So even before the user confirms the installation? Are you sure that it's a correct behavior? - How do you get the number from the texts? Is it it's order number? - The normal number: So do you mean textual representation of the number?

Comment: Is a normal behavior that I have always used in my installers, my goal is for the user to select an item from the bombobox, which will be 18 items and then this item according to the order (01; 02; 03 ...; 18), convert it to A number to write to the INI file.
Example: item N ° 1: cadet; Value in INI: 01. and so on until the 18th, in short everything you have said you

Comment: Well, if you have already used this in your installers, you must have some code. Show us. And edit your question with your explanation of "normal number".

Comment: Basically, I see 3 tasks here: 1) Generating the "normal number" 2) Triggering save on custom page after the components section (though I strongly disagree with this) 3) The actual writing an INI file. - Which of these do you have problem with?

Comment: I was referring to the part of when the user enters the data in the installer, it is a behavior that I have always used, but the combobox is new to me and so I am asking for help, ok it will be edited

Comment: @MartinPrikryl the first, the generation of the number in the INI file with items in combobox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution is using a [scripted constant](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptconstants) in the INI section:

```pascal
[INI]
Filename: "{app}\rev.ini"; Section: "steamclient"; \
    Key: "RankLevel"; String: "{code:GetRankLevel}"

[Code]

{ ... }

function GetRankLevel(Param: string): string;
begin
  Result := Format('%.2d', [NewComboBox1.ItemIndex + 1]);
end;
```

---

Though this will not write the INI file *"in a custom page after the components section"*. It will write it only during the actual installation, what is the correct behavior, imho.

---

See also [Save Inno Setup custom page field values to an INI file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4053287/850848#44062243).